# AVAssetWriter - How do I get a byte count of what has been written?

Tags: filesize, avassetwriter, avasset

I am writing a MOV file, in which I am supplying a bunch of CMSampleBuffers to pass along to an AVAssetWriterInput object.
While this is going on, I am tracking the byte size of the compressed data inside the CMSampleBuffers to write to a log file on the system.
The only thing that I am missing, is the MOV header size.

The difference between my count and the saved file size, is typically about 2000 bytes or so of data. I can't figure out how to get the exact size written to the file system from AVAssetWriter.

Now, I could just find the file size after the MOV file is closed, but for some reason, NSFileSystemManager "attributesOfItemAtPath" "NSFileSize" never matches the byte count with I look at the file in the bash shell.

Suggestions are welcome!

bob.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? Also how did you "track the byte size of the compressed data inside the CMSampleBuffer" ? I'm tried doing this by adding up the CMSampleBufferGetTotalSampleSize of each sample buffer, but my total byte size was 10x smaller than the final file size given by FileManager.default.fileSize(atPath:).